# Pick date range in jQuery-UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am developing a site where i am using jQuery-UI datepicker, the problem is i have to select all dates and put it into an array when the user select a start date and end date using `a aingle` jquery UI datepicker.

i checked the jQuery-UI documentation but found nothing that solve my problem.

I want **date-range** to be picked up like this.

[image]

i have to use **jQuery-UI**, so any useful idea will be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created `datepicker` like this, so no need for more answers. **Thanks**

Here is working **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m_tanzi/3examhwg/)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method:

1.The user clicks the 2 dates

2.You save them as two variables(startDate,endDate)

3.you make a loop:

```
var numberOfDaysToAdd=0
var startDate;
var endDate;
var dateCheck=startDate;
var DatetoAddInArray = startDate;
var  array = [];
while(DatetoAddInArray!=endDate){
    //every time you check if the date is equal to the endDate
    //if  is not you add it in the array with the dates and then
    //you increase the index.
    //the while loop ends when you find the end  Date
    //You can change your code to add or not the start and the end dates
    numberOfDaysToAdd++;
    DatetoAddInArray.setDate(DatetoAddInArray.getDate()+numberOfDaysToAdd);
    array[numberOfDaysToAdd-1]=DatetoAddInArray;
 }
```

The above could be an easy way to store all the dates from the start to the end date.

(!) If the datepicker allows the user to click a startDate and then click a endDate that is before the startDate, you have to alert a message to the user to select a correct range.

Thanks.